# Can I initialize a Node project from a package as template?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarn-v2

I wonder if I can initialize a new Node project using an existing package as a template?
Instead of having the package as a dependency, I would like the project to be a copy of the package.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using `npm pack <package>`. It downloads the package as a tarball. Unfortunately, it seems like there is not a similar function for `yarn` to download a package this way.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [npm init](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-init) command. You can create your own CLI which installs the package, copies files into the target directory, then removes the package. If you follow `npm` documentation your installer could be run in this way:

```
npm init <installer-name>
```

or:

```
npm init @scope/<installer-name>
```

Using `npm init` (or `npm create` which is an alias to `npm init`) is also compatible with: [yarn create](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/create/)